# Выхватить кадр с соотношением сторон

Tags: javascript

```
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 350, 198);
```

Не совсем понимаю как это работает.
Вопрос в том, как выхватить кадр из видео так, чтобы сохранить соотношение сторон. Допустим если брать видео у которого высота больше, а ширина меньше в двое. То полученный кадр будет размытым под размеры(соотношение сторон 350/198).

В целом, возможно просто выхватить кадр с теми размерами(соотношением сторон), какие они есть. И на выходе получить canvas с соотношением сторон кадра?

Comment: Вообще у элемента `<video>`, есть пропорции `videoHeight` и `videoWidth`, это собственно указывают на высоту и ширину самого видео (НЕ элемента), если это конечно то, что вы хотели.

Comment: Возможно поместить кадр не в canvas, а в img. Что та canvas, высота одна, а кадр в  нем не адаптируется по размеры, под размеры canvas